# object null reference exception disappears after iisreset

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I get Object Null Reference after I publish my codes on server side, while I don't get it on my pc. But the question is **why after IISReset, problem disappears for some hours!**

Comment: Also App Pool Recycle solves the problem for some hours!

Comment: First of all, you need to figure out what is the cause of the Object Null Reference. IIS restart will stop the entire Web server, so the application will re-run. Recycling the application pool is the same, it will affect the application in the application pool and make it run again. In other words, it is not IIS that solves the problem, but the application reruns. So I suggest that you check the code in the application again and improve the parts that may go wrong.